# remove vertical white space background in datepicker

Tags: android, datepicker

any one know how to remove the white vertical thing in the right of datepicker?
i haven't found any solution yet for this background problem.

[clik here to link for sreenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0KmrE.jpg)

**layout xml file** for the activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:background="@drawable/background_detail_destination"
     android:padding="10dp"
     tools:context="com.example.michael.finalproject.Detail_Destination">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="Choose Date"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"/>

<DatePicker
    android:id="@+id/datepic"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
    android:calendarTextColor="@android:color/background_light">
</DatePicker>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnplantravel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
    android:text="Plan Travel" />

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**java file**

```
private DatePicker datepic;

datepic = findViewById(R.id.datepic);
datepic.setBackground(new ColorDrawable(Color.WHITE));
```

Comment: send the screenshot

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0KmrE.jpg

Comment: show the full xml file...check wether you have given any padding or margin in the parent layout..

Comment: which layout did you take as the parent layout ? Linear??

Comment: here is my code for the layout xml file. and yes i give padding to the parent layout

Comment: try to make the width of date picker wrap content ...and make the gravity of linear layout center and check how it looks

Comment: it still the same nothing change. the date picker still have the vertical white background.